# Create a query from API JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am using Brightspace APIs. I am able to get the JSON data, but I can not search for a field.
Here is the JSON output:

```
{
    "PagingInfo": {
        "Bookmark": "392854",
        "HasMoreItems": false
    },
    "Items": [
        {
            "User": {
                "Identifier": "58686",
                "DisplayName": "SDent",
                "EmailAddress": "",
                "OrgDefinedId": "009700001",
                "ProfileBadgeUrl": null,
                "ProfileIdentifier": "Kx9BKKwtp3"
            },
            "Role": {
                "Id": 103,
                "Code": "01",
                "Name": "Student"
            }
        },
        {
            "User": {
                "Identifier": "58687",
                "DisplayName": "S2Dent",
                "OrgDefinedId": "009700002",
                "ProfileBadgeUrl": null,
                "ProfileIdentifier": "sybvFAVR3N"
            },
            "Role": {
                "Id": 103,
                "Code": "01",
                "Name": "Student"
            }
        },
        {
            "User": {
                "Identifier": "361398",
                "DisplayName": "JD",
                "OrgDefinedId": "0035678",
                "ProfileBadgeUrl": null,
                "ProfileIdentifier": "FIBX5sZOtu"
            },
            "Role": {
                "Id": 103,
                "Code": "01",
                "Name": "Student"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I do to get the OrgDefinedId field where it is equal to 009700001? I'm not using database. 
Here is how I get the Json data. I appreciate any help.

```
function getStudentID(orgUnitId){
  hideData();
  document.getElementById("GETField").checked = true;
  document.getElementById("actionField").value = "/d2l/api/lp/1.0/enrollments/orgUnits/"+orgUnitId+"/users/";
  }
```

Comment: What have you tried? So far it looks like there is no attempt to get the information, and other than your JSON file you haven't posted relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `find` method.

```js
let jsonObj = {
    "PagingInfo": {
        "Bookmark": "392854",
        "HasMoreItems": false
    },
    "Items": [
        {
            "User": {
                "Identifier": "58686",
                "DisplayName": "SDent",
                "EmailAddress": "",
                "OrgDefinedId": "009700001",
                "ProfileBadgeUrl": null,
                "ProfileIdentifier": "Kx9BKKwtp3"
            },
            "Role": {
                "Id": 103,
                "Code": "01",
                "Name": "Student"
            }
        },
        {
            "User": {
                "Identifier": "58687",
                "DisplayName": "S2Dent",
                "OrgDefinedId": "009700002",
                "ProfileBadgeUrl": null,
                "ProfileIdentifier": "sybvFAVR3N"
            },
            "Role": {
                "Id": 103,
                "Code": "01",
                "Name": "Student"
            }
        },
        {
            "User": {
                "Identifier": "361398",
                "DisplayName": "JD",
                "OrgDefinedId": "0035678",
                "ProfileBadgeUrl": null,
                "ProfileIdentifier": "FIBX5sZOtu"
            },
            "Role": {
                "Id": 103,
                "Code": "01",
                "Name": "Student"
            }
        }
    ]
}

let result = jsonObj.Items.find(item=> item.User.OrgDefinedId==="009700001")
console.log(result)
```

Comment: How do I get the Json into jsonObj? I have JS that gets it: ` $('#responseField').val(format(output.response));`

Comment: If you already have the JSON, you have to convert it into javascript object: `let obj = JSON.parse(strJson);`

Comment: I'm still doing something wrong...           `success: function(data) {
            var output = {};
            if(data == '') {
              output.response = 'Success!';
            } else {
              try {
                output = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
              } catch(e) {
                output = "Unexpected non-JSON response from the server: " + data;
              }
            }
            $('#statusField').val(output.statusCode);

            let obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);//gets the json
            $('#responseField').val(obj); //prints the arr`

Comment: It's difficult to know what's happening. Try to use http://jsfiddle.net to see your problem.

Comment: It's still difficult. This code will not show the same errors that you have on your computer, because there are not html code, the library, and variables. Have you tried printing `data` in the `success` method? what is the error?